# cloudformation apigateway missing HTTP Status: Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am standing up an API Gateway resource using cloudformation, and I noticed that the Method Response field does not contain `HTTP Status: Proxy` as it does if you create a proxy resource from the console.

My CF code:

```
  Api:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - 'PRIVATE'
      Name: 'why_did_aws_have_to_crash_today_APIG'
  Resource:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt Api.RootResourceId
      PathPart: '{proxy+}'
      RestApiId: !Ref Api
  Method:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref Api
      ResourceId: !Ref Resource
      HttpMethod: ANY
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: ANY
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        Uri: arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:why-did-aws-have-to-crash-today/invocations
```

[image]

Comment: So what is your question? The API does not work? Any errors?

Comment: If there isn't a method response configured, then wouldn't there be an error?

Comment: I'm not sure. Have you checked? Maybe by default it will be set?

Comment: failing with 500, {"message": "Internal server error"}

Comment: "why-did-aws-have-to-crash-today" :-)

Comment: @Marcin sad day for us-east-1'ers

Comment: Not the first time nor last time. Its further shows that cloud is not a golden solution to any possible availability issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it should be:

```
IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
```

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html):

> or Lambda integrations, you **must use the HTTP method of POST** for the integration request,

Second, if you want to explicitly add `MethodResponses`, then it should be:

```
      MethodResponses: 
        - ResponseModels: {"application/json": "Empty"}
          StatusCode: 200
```

Comment: And why should it be IntegrationHttpMethod: POST......

Comment: @dataviews I updated the answer.

Comment: It looks like I was facing another issue. It's strange that I can't get that HTTP Status: Proxy message to show under Method Response when I use CF, but my 500 issue was related to the APIG not having permissions to invoke the proxy service (lambda). If you set it up from console, you are prompted to give it permissions, where as in CF you are not. And I have IntegrationHttpMethod: set to ANY and it works, however after seeing this documentation I will update to be POST, where HttpMethod will still stay as ANY

Comment: I'll also point out that as long as your proxy (lambda) handles the response status / message, it appears that you do not need MethodResponses. At least, I am not using this now. I believe I saw this in the documentation somewhere, as long as you are using a proxy to lambda

Comment: @dataviews That was my initial comment about `MethodResponses`.